# Version number validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

My product version number is of the format "P.Q.R", where P, Q, R are digits. The valid inputs are "P", "P.Q", "P.Q.R".

I wrote regular expression performing an `OR` operation.

```
(^\d+$) | (^\d+.\d+$) | (^\d+.\d+.\d$)
```

Is there much simpler way to write using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
^\d+(\.\d+){0,2}$
```

The `\d+` indicates any number of digits. The `(\.\d+)` indicates a dot followed by any number of digits, and the `{0,2}` means the last group can be repeated 0-2 times. The `^` and `$` indicate the start and end of the string, so the regex will match the whole thing.

Comment: Although the OP seems to have an understanding of regular expressions, you might want to explain in more detail what this does

Comment: @lan Reading JS docs to understand what it means. I started learning regular expressions. It could have been easier if PlasmaPower explained what it means.